# Setting time interval on 2 sounds arrays

Tags: ios, ipad, audio, cocos2d-iphone

I got a button that plays 2 sounds arrays setted in my init scene:

```
NSString * soundName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d%@.mp3", levelNumber, i+1, language];

NSString * soundName2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%db%@.mp3", levelNumber, i+1, language];

CDBufferLoadRequest * request = [[CDBufferLoadRequest alloc] init:(1001+i) filePath:soundName];
[loadRequests addObject:request];
[request release];

CDBufferLoadRequest * request2 = [[CDBufferLoadRequest alloc] init:(1009+i) filePath:soundName2];
[loadRequests addObject:request2];
[request2 release];
```

and they are called when I click on my button. The method when clicked the button is this one:

```
-(void) soundTruck
{
    [soundEngine stopAllSounds];
    [soundEngine playSound:(1000+tag) sourceGroupId:1 pitch:1 pan:1 gain:1.0f loop:NO];
    NSLog(@"sound activated");

    [soundEngine playSound:(1008+tag) sourceGroupId:1 pitch:1 pan:1 gain:1.0f loop:NO];
    NSLog(@"sound activated");
}
```

The thing is that I want to set an interval between this 2 sounds to set the first one, and then the second. Right now, with this code, it only plays the second one. Can someone teach me how to set sound intervals?

Comment: If you are using cocos2d. then you can use CCDelay for creating delay and CCCallFunction for calling functions. And after that CCSequence for creating a sequence of CCCallFunc(Playing first set),CCDelay(interval) and then CCCallFunc(playing second set). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSTimer class ,it will help u.

Comment: Is NSTimer available for iOS?

Comment: yes,it available in iOS,please read enclosed link  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

Comment: How to include it? I tried #import <NSTimer.h> - but file can not be found. In the documentation there is  OS X v10.0 and later, but there is no iOS.

Comment: it works on iOS, thanks. In documentation OS X stated only, no iOS.